# Pointers to structs in C vs pointers to arrays

Tags: c, pointers

Do pointers to structures in C work differently than other pointers?
For example in this code:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void insert(node **head, int data) {
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}

int main() {
    node *head = NULL;
    insert(&head, 6);
```

Why do I have to use a pointer to a pointer and can't use the variable `head` in the `insert` function like in this example with arrays:

```
void moidify(int *arr) {
    *arr = 3;
}

int main() {
    int *array = malloc(8);
    *array = 1;
    *(array + 1) = 2;
    moidify(array);
}
```

Here I don't have to pass `&array` to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand how pointers works to get this one.
Here, the variable `array` is not properly speaking, an array. It's a pointer toward a memory space, of size `8 * sizeof(int)`. It contains only an address. From this address you can access the values of the array, you move using this address, to the rightfully memory space you want to fill or read.

Once that understood, when you call the `moidify` function, you are not passing the array. Nor the memory space. You are passing, the address of the memory space. The function gets a copy of the given address, in the argument variable `int *arr`.

Hence, you can use it the same way you use it from the `main` function.

If you wanted to change the address toward which the `array` variable would go, you would need to specify `&array` to the receiving function, which would then use an `int **` argument variable.

Your example with struct is similar to this last part I just described, you want to change toward which address `head` is pointing, so, you need to give `&head` to the function. To get the address of `head`, and be able to modify the contained address.

You use an address, to access the memory space called `head`, to modify the address inside the memory space called `head`, which point toward another memory space, where your struct truly belongs.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. If you want to change the value of the variable you send in to `function` in such a way that the change is visible in the function that called `function`, you need to supply its address to `function`, which is what you do when taking the address of `head`.

In `moidify(array)` you send in a pointer to the first element in `array` which is why modifying the array data works. If you would like to modify the `array` variable itself (by making it potentially point somewhere else), you would have to take its address too. Example:

```c
void moidify(int **arr) {
    *arr = realloc(*arr, 128);
    if(*arr == NULL) {
        perror(__func__);
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int *array = malloc(8);
    *array = 1;
    *(array + 1) = 2;
    moidify(&array);
}
```